# Concatenating relative transformations to obtain a global transformation

Tags: ros, navigation, odometry, visual-odometry, eigen

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi guys,

I am trying to implement a visual odometry system that matches features viewed by sequential frames and calculating the rigid body transformation between the corresponding points using RANSAC. I am successfully obtaining the ransac transformation that aligns the points obtained by the two frames. The relative transformation is of type `Eigen::Matrix4f relative_transformation` . I would like to concatenate (sum up) all the relative transformation in order to obtain a global transformation. I don't think I am doing it correctly:

```
//class attributes
Eigen::Matrix4f global_transformation== Eigen::Matrix4f::Identity(4,4);;
Eigen::Matrix4f relative_transformation;
tf::Transform transform;

void process(){
relative_transformation=calculate_ransac_relative_transformation();
global_transformation = global_transformation*relative_transformation;

Eigen::Matrix4d global_transformation_(global_transformation.cast<double>());
Eigen::Affine3d affine(global_transformation_);
tf::TransformEigenToTF(affine, transform);
static tf::TransformBroadcaster br;
br.sendTransform(tf::StampedTransform(transform, ros::Time::now(), "/odom",  "Global_transformation"));
}
```

When viewing the transformation in RVIZ, it keeps jumping around even if the camera is not moving. Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Any help would be much appreciated.
Thanks,

Khalid

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/62436/concatenating-relative-transformations-to-obtain-a-global-transformation/) by [K_Yousif](https://answers.ros.org/users/3767/k_yousif/) on ROS Answers with karma: 735 on 2013-05-08

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sai](https://answers.ros.org/users/2967/sai/) on 2014-03-30**:
Hi, how did you solve the problem ?

**Comment by [Mobile_robot](https://answers.ros.org/users/11921/mobile_robot/) on 2014-07-01**:
Hello Khalid,

I am trying to use the same procedure, I am using Groovy and Ubuntu 12.04.

The problem is that it says :   "  ‘TransformEigenToTF’ is not a member of ‘tf’  " !!

as I understood I should add the header file : <tf_conversions/tf_eigen.h> but I have the problem, it says that for computer Eigein/Core.h is not clear!!

Can you please tell me how you did that?

Thanks
Hamed

**Comment by [K_Yousif](https://answers.ros.org/users/3767/k_yousif/) on 2014-07-09**:
Hi Hamed, Try transformEigenToTF (with the small t instead of capital T).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The above procedure is correct, there was jumping or incorrect transformation every now and then which ruins the estimate, therefore I added an if statement that if the relative transformation is > than a specified threshold, then ignore it and set the relative transformation to the identity.

---

Originally posted by [K_Yousif](https://answers.ros.org/users/3767/k_yousif/) with karma: 735 on 2014-03-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1